# How are the coefficients of a polynomial indexed?

Tags: polynomials

Say I have $P(x) = a_{n}x^{n} + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + a_{0}$.

If I were to say "the n'th coefficient of P", without having written $P$ explicitly as above, would that be referring to $a_{0}$ or $a_{n}$?

I suspect the answer to be $a_n$, but I've never seen the convention used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, instead of "the $n$-th" coefficient one says the *leading coefficient* of the leading monomial $x^n$. So $lc(P)=a_n$. The "$n$-th coefficient" also may depend on whether you write the polynomial as
$$
P=a_0+a_1x^1+\cdots a_nx^n,
$$

or, like you did, as
$$
P=a_nx^n+\cdots +a_1x^1+a_0
$$
One can say "the coefficient of degree $k$", to name $a_k$ in $P$, i.e., for $a_kx^k$.

Comment: Yeah, but how do I refer to an arbitrary coefficient in the coefficient list? I need to refer to something like "the k'th coefficient of the characteristic polynomial of this n*n matrix". It'd be easier than writing it  out explicitly.

Comment: How do you refer to it? Very easy, as the coefficient of degree $k$, meaning in $a_kx^k$. So of degree two, it would be $a_2$.

Comment: Duh, that was easy. Thank you :).